# Magento 2 - translating strings in JS/KO

Tags: magento, translation

I need to translate the frontend of magento 2 to pt_BR, but I'm having a problem to translate the strings that are generated by the JS/KO. All my pages are translated normally with the .csv, but the JS/KO strings aren't. For example, I want to translate the button "GO TO CHECKOUT" from mini-cart, but I can't... How can I get it ? Anyone have any ideia to solve this ? I already flush the cache, run the command bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy, but didn't work for me.

Comment: Try creating language package as exampled here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-example2 Magento will generate js-translations.json file only when you will have language package. (Don't ask my why is this like that, there are a lot of mysteries in this crappy system)

Answer (score 3):

Check if the file `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>/js-translation.json` exists and if it only contains `[]`.

If so, you've been affected by a Magento 2 bug (`js-translation.json` not being generated properly).

The workaround is to remove this file and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <locale>`. This should populate the file and make JS/KO translations work. You may also want to change file permissions on `js-translation.json` to prevent Magento from overwriting it again with `[]`.

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2056#issuecomment-259641599

Comment: in my case the js-translation.json was rendered perfectly with the translation.
Can you please answer to my question - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307308/magento-2-knockout-js-translation-is-not-working/307312#307312